# .Net email web services

Tags: c#, asp.net

I recently create a web services to send email. the code as follow:

```
        if (notiInput.type == "Register")
        {
            emailSubject = "Kad Mesra - ";
            bodyTitle = "Below are the Kad Mesra registration details for the individual:";
        }

        else if (notiInput.type == "Replacement")
        {
            emailSubject = "Kad Mesra Replacement - ";
            bodyTitle = "Below are the Kad Mesra replacement details for the individual:";
        }
```

My question is, is it possible for me to edit my emailSubject in html page(which i have to create i guess) so that i don't have to always edit in my source code?

Comment: I'm not sure I got you.

Comment: where is your html page?

Comment: @KaushikMaheta i haven't create the html page yet. cause i'm not sure whether this method works.

Comment: @PeiChin, I suggest you to create html page with content when send email that time read created html page and replace subject, title value after pass it to email body.

Comment: @PeiChin What you can do is  : Create a HTML page with the editor, use the text to fill the body title. You can also set HTML true in email.

Comment: @BabekoofCoder but i need to have a database to store the value right?

Comment: You can use a DB or you can use a Physical Text file to store the same. DB is more secure and provides better backup option but in case of a physical text file you may want to back that up every day. Your wish. If you wish I can mention the same in the answer

Comment: @BabekoofCoder i would love to know how to use DB if you may tell :)